# What is the capacity of a WWII Submarine battery in kWh?

Tags: electrical-engineering, battery

After reading about submarines in World War II, I was curious about their battery capacity, specifically in comparison to modern Battery Electric Vehicles (ie Tesla, Bolt, Leaf, i3, etc).

I haven't been able to find a source that either answers the question in kWh or gives me enough information to calculate it myself.

**My current guess is about 30 kWh**, based on a figure of 12000 Ah in a 120 cell system, and a voltage of 2.75 V - 1.05 V

I would accept an answer for any class of submarine in WWII, but I was looking at the US Balao class.

Comment: What was the chemistry used in the batteries you are looking at?

Comment: @SolarMike Lead Acid

Comment: Old topic but I am not sure how the maths are done... With lead acid, 2.25V nominal x 120cells in series and 12000Ah cells we get about 3MWh, not 30kWh... maybe Ah rating is wrong.

Comment: @ÁlvaroSatuéCrespo my comment to you was lost (mod changing your answer to a comment) so repeating it: are you assuming each cell has a capacity of 12000Ah ?

Comment: @ÁlvaroSatuéCrespo It's been a while since I asked this question, I wish I had stated it better.The 12000Ah refers to the whole system, not one cell; so it's 2.25*12000 = 27000 V*Ah = 27000 Wh = 27kWh. I do not recall where I got the figure of 100 Ah per cell in this class of submarine.

Comment: Ok I was assuming there was 120cells in series (120x2.25V) and as parallels as needed for 12000Ah. I thought submarines were provided with much bigger batteries for enought immersion time. Now I understand why they are transitioning to lithium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collecting bits from sites,

[fleetsubmarines](https://fleetsubmarine.com/battery.html)

> World War II American fleet submarines had two batteries, each
>   composed of 126 cells. By comparison, a 12-volt car battery contains
>   only 6 cells, each producing about 2.25 volts when fully charged, with
>   a maximum power output of about 45-50 amps. Each cell in a submarine
>   battery produces from 1.06 volts when fully discharged, to 2.75 volts
>   at the optimum output, so connecting the 126 cells in each battery in
>   series gives a usable output of from about 210 to 350 volts, and a
>   power output of as much as 15,000 amps with both batteries connected
>   in parallel.
>   (no mention of total amp-hrs)

[quora](https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-a-diesel-submarine-have-to-run-its-engines-to-fully-charge-its-batteries)

> My submarines (Oberon class of the 1960s-1990s) had two lead acid
>   batteries containing 224 cells each with a nominal voltage of 440
>   volts.. The cells were rated 74.20 ampere-hours at a 5 hour rate
>   (nominal voltage of each cell was 2.2 V)

448*74*2.2 = 73kWh

[uboat.net](https://uboat.net/articles/id/54)

> The US Navy "Balao" type submarine (1944/45) was fitted with 4 four
>   Elliot Main (Electric Motors) two on each shaft, with a total
>   horsepower of 2,740. While submerged, these motors were powered by two
>   massive (each cell weighing 1650#) 126-cell batteries (in series)
>   capable of delivering 5,320 Amp/Hrs each.

Assuming they meant Amp-hrs, and guessing 2.2 V per cell, 2.2 * 2*5320 = 23.4 kWh